Overwrite default drawing tools in GEE
I try to use the default drawing tools in GEE to get an area of interest (e.g., polygon, point, rectangular). What I want now is to delete the previous geometry if exists and draw a new geometry each time. In other word, I want to get new geometry each time and save it into variable called aoi. Ultimately, I want to publish an app, where user can draw a new geometry each time and plot something from that particular geometry. here is sample code.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/e1b8495b7d30d927fbebe0d782d5b46d

You can create a function to clear the drawn geometries and call it every time you finish processing.
// Get the drawing tools.
var dt = Map.drawingTools();

// Function that deletes drawn geometries.
var clearAOI = function() {
  dt.layers().reset();
};

// Calls the function to clear any drawn geometries.
clearAOI();

var generateChart = function() {
  // Get the drawn AOI.
  var aoi = dt.layers().get(0).geometries().get(0);
  
  // Do something with the AOI.
  // ...
  
  // Create a chart.
  var data = ee.List([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  var chart = ui.Chart.array.values(data, 0, data)
    .setChartType('ColumnChart');
  
  // You can also add the chart to the map.
  print(chart);
  
  clearAOI();
};

dt.onDraw(generateChart);

You can also use the clearAOI function as a button callback.
